# libao compiling in window

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

I downloaded the source of libao.  Do I need to compile it into a library/dll for windows or do I use the source as is.

Has anyone done this before? libao is an audio library, which I found here: http://www.xiph.org/ao/

Comment: though it was closed . add a windows solution :https://github.com/stkchp/libao-windows

Answer (score 1):

Like plenty of open source projets, you need to compile it first before using it, unless you want to keep every required source codes along with your project and compile them each time. This can be a mess since you can (and more likely will) alterate something in the library one day or another. For that reason, you should compile it into something then link to it.